# C# Replace some char from a Regex Match

Tags: c#, regex

Let's see, if I can express myself.

I want to replace some characters from the result of a previous match, and keep the changes in the original string.

For example, I have this string:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetur adipiscing elit", sed do eiusmod tempor "incididunt ut labore" et dolore "magna" aliqua.*

And I want to replace in the text inside quotes "", all "o" character for an "A" character.

So first match is for quoted text:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **"consectetur adipiscing elit"**, sed do eiusmod tempor **"incididunt ut labore"** et dolore **"magna"** aliqua.*

And the second match will be the "o" inside that new strings:

*"c**o**nsectetur adipiscing elit"
"incididunt ut lab**o**re"
"magna"*

So, I get the first quoted text with Regex `"\"([^\"*])\""`,
but after I'm stuck and can't figure, how to proceed for the next step, the result should be like this:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "c**A**nsectetur adipiscing elit", sed do eiusmod tempor "incididunt ut lab**A**re" et dolore "magna" aliqua.*

Thank you.

Comment: The pattern must be `"\"[^\"]*\""`, and all you need then is `Regex.Replace(text, "\"[^\"]*\"", x => x.Value.Replace("o", "A"))`

Comment: I'm not even sure I'd use regex for this; string to char array/stringbuilder, loop over it, every time `"` is encountered, toggle replacemode true<-->false, and when in replacemode is true, if char is 'o' change to 'A'..